# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:Cannot find any provider supporting AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, jce

I was trying to encrypt data using AES algorithm.
However, with the following exception has occurred.

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
    Cannot find any provider supporting AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING
```

Someone know a solution to this issue?
My JDK's version is 1.7.

Comment: Note that ECB is not CPA secure, use CBC instead (if you just want confidentiality of stored data).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You don't want to specify PKCS#7 padding for block cipher use. You want to specify PKCS#5 padding. PKCS#5 is specified for use with block ciphers while PKCS#7 is not (it's use for different places like in S/MIME). I will point out that PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 actually specify exactly the same type of padding (they are the same!), but it's called #5 when used in this context. :)

So, instead of `"AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING"`, you want `"AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING"`. This is a cipher implementation that every implementation of the Java platform is required to support. See the [documentation of the `Cipher` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer.Then JCE provider does not support PKCS7PADDING?

Comment: Correct. It does not (well, since #5 and #7 are the same padding...I guess you could say it does?). And, you're welcome. Remember to Accept the answer if you're happy with it. :)

Comment: This answer is okay, but a little confusing because you *do* want to use PKCS #7 padding for a block cipher. It's just that `PKCS7Padding` is the wrong name, according to the [Standard Algorithm Names.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) PKCS #7 uses this padding scheme for padding messages that are encrypted with block ciphers. It doesn't matter what the larger context is.

Comment: And to add to the confusion, .NET call the exact same padding algorithm [PKCS7 padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.aspx).

Comment: While Java considers PKCS5 and PKCS7 padding to be the "same" (and one should always use the string "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" because "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" will cause NoSuchAlgorithmException to be thrown when initializing an AES block cipher using the Java crypto API), I consider this a gross misnaming in the Java platform because the pure technical definitions of these paddings are not the same.  PKCS5 explicitly defines its block size as being strictly 8 bytes, while PKCS7 is defined for block sizes from 1 to 255 (with block sizes of 8 bytes being the same thing as PKCS5).

Comment: The answer is kind of correct, but the explanation is definitely not. If the specification is any indication, then PKCS#5 padding should only be used for password based encryption, as that is what PKCS#5 specifies. To disallow PKCS#7 padding as general padding for a block cipher because PKCS#7 mainly specifies the Cryptographic Message Syntax is therefore bunk. Only the last sentence makes sense (but that's most of the answer, fortunately)

Comment: To make my crypto lib in Java and .NET understand each other, I have to use PKCS#5 (Java) ~ PKCS7 (.NET). Oh my god, thanks for the challenge...

Comment: 2020: helpful regarding a java6-decryption for a value encrypted with java8, has been done with commons-codes, which resulted in a NoSuchMethodException, maybe because of a commons-codec 1.2 in an "quite" old JBOSS classpath - THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use  AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding then bouncy castle will support  ht[tp://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html)

Comment: True but it's the same padding algorithm underneath.

Answer (score 4):

For a very comprehensive explanation of the issue that includes the text of the PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 cryptographic standards, please take a look [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).

---

PKCS#5 padding means padding 1 to 8 bytes. The padding bytes themselves contain the amount of padding bytes encoded as a byte. PKCS#5 padding was specified for DES, but it would be suitable for any block cipher with a block size of 8 bytes.

Now the DES specifications and even the PKCS#5 specification for password based encryption precede and Java by quite a long time. AES was only standardized in 2002, long after Java and even Java 2 was introduced. So (triple) DES and PKCS#5 padding was integrated into Java before AES made its appearance.

When Java - or more precisely, the Sun JCE provider - gained AES functionality it required a padding method for a block size of 16 bytes. PKCS#7 specifies this padding method that [is identical to PKCS#5 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172), except that it is defined for block sizes of 2 to 255 bytes (the maximum  value of a byte if it encodes a zero based unsigned integer). However, the padding method was already there; it was named `"PKCS5Padding"`. So instead of introducing a new name, `"PKCS5Padding"` was simply re-used.

By now the Sun provider should really support `"PKCS7Padding"` as PKCS#5 padding is simply incorrect. It's not just a Java naming issue, it's an issue for any developer that tries to implement cryptographic protocols or port other applications to Java. For now however, you should use `"PKCS5Padding"` instead of `"PKCS7Padding"`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Step1: Add bcprov-ext-jdk16-1.46.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk16/1.46) to your project

Step2: Add line "Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());" to bebore init Cipher common

Then, run the project, OK, successfully decrypted.

Comment: This solution worked when the environment was standalone Java but didn't work on Android. For Android the solution is in this thread itself.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71250536/1711555

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following solution if the environment was **Android** and you were trying to read the **Encrypted Private Key or Passphrase protected Private Key** in PKCS8 format from the file.

The Exception that I received was as follows:

```
W/System.err: org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: No provider found for 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source:60)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
W/System.err: Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: No provider found for 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source:322)
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source:6)
W/System.err:   ... 8 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No provider found for 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.createCipher(Cipher.java:736)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:619)
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.DefaultJcaJceHelper.createCipher(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source:101)
W/System.err:   ... 9 more
```

The only solution that worked was to set the Provider as Bouncy Castle like below:

```
InputDecryptorProvider decryptorProvider = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder()
    .setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
    .build(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.password).toCharArray());
```

The complete block code would look like this:

```
privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replace("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
byte[] keyStringBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(privateKeyString);
ASN1Sequence asn1Sequence = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(keyStringBytes);
PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pkcs8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo = new PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(
    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(asn1Sequence));
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
InputDecryptorProvider decryptorProvider = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder()
    .setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
    .build(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.password).toCharArray());
PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = pkcs8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decryptorProvider);
mPrivateKey = converter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);
```