# AES Decryption iv error: must be a class [B value

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, aes, coldfusion-10

I received the following data from a vendor so that we can decrypt data on our end.

```
Algorithm : AES 256bit
Key : test123xxxxxx
Key Length : 32
Initialize Vector: ei8B3hcD8VhnN_cK
Built in methods : YES (From inbuilt class CommonCryptor.h method with variable CCCryptorStatus).
```

Please note I have no idea if the last line has any relevance to our decryption.

I attempted the following on a sample string that we should be able to decode.

```
<cfset item = "eLgExhcox5Ro1kPB1OlJP1w6tEJ3x94gM/QJS5dCZkyjEVfNjIid3R7JP4l1WZD1" />

<cfoutput>#decrypt(#item#, #key#, 'AES', 'Base64', #iv# )#</cfoutput>
```

The error I receive is: **The value of parameter 5, which is currently ei8B3hcD8VhnN_cK, must be a class [B value.** of which I cannot find anything about.

I am also assuming the encoding is Base64 of which I am finding out from the vendor. Is there anything else I'm missing.

Comment: May also want to verify the padding scheme they are using. CF defaults to PKCS5Padding, but you can change it if needed via the algorithm string ie "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"

Comment: I just found out the vendor uses PKCS7 padding. Do I modify the number in the above algorithm accordingly?

Comment: The two are equivalent, up to a certain block size. So as long as they are not using a block size greater than 16, PKCS5 should be fine.  After that you need to use PKCS7 (not supported by core java, try BouncyCastle) For more details see * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193567/java-security-nosuchalgorithmexceptioncannot-find-any-provider-supporting-aes-e * http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be it is complaining that the IV value is not binary. If your IV value is a base64 string, use `binaryDecode(yourIVString, "base64")` to get the binary value.

> a class [B value

The `[B` refers to the expected object: an array of bytes. Apparently `[B` is the ["binary name [...] as specified by the Java Language Specification (§13.1)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object). You will see the same thing if you create a `byte[]` array and dump the class name:

```
 // show binary and canonical class names
 arr = javacast("byte[]", [1]);
 writeOutput("name="& arr.getClass().name);
 writeOutput("<br>canonicalName="& arr.getClass().canonicalName);
```

Side note, if you are using a 256 bit key, be sure you have installed the [(JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files first](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html). Otherwise, you are limited to 128 bit keys maximum.

Comment: I added `binaryDecode(IVString, 'base64')` and now it throws **The input and output encodings are not same.**

Comment: (Edit) Did you change the CF code to use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` instead of just `AES`?  Also, did you install the JCE Unlimited Strength files, as noted above (restart required)?

Comment: Yes to `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, no to the JCE since the vendor came back and said it was 128-bit encrypted only.

Comment: Hm... what is the new key size? Do you have a sanitized example with dummy keys you can post?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Wow, what a throwback follow-up. No, I have not. It's fallen to the bottom of the to-do pile since then.

Comment: It has only been a year ;-)  Just came across this one again and was curious. If it ever makes its way to the top of pile, drop a comment and let me know. Encryption problems are always fun :)