# Android AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING generate key bouncy castle

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I want to generate Random key using  `AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING` but java does not support `PKCS7` padding and in my algo I have to use the same padding, bouncy castle does support `PKCS7PADDING` but I am unable to understand how to generate key using that

My code :

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());


private byte[] generateSessionKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING", "BC");
        kgen.init(SYMMETRIC_KEY_SIZE);
        SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
        return key.getEncoded();
}
```

I am receiving error of no such algorithm

Comment: Why would you use ECB anyway? http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: its requirement we cant change any of the given algo list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key generation for AES does not have to do anything with padding. Padding is required for some modes of operation such as ECB and CBC. But the key itself doesn't rely on the mode *or* the padding. So you should just use:

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
```

which will undoubtedly work.

---

Do not use PKCS#7 padding, substitute `"PKCS5Padding"` for `"PKCS7Padding"`.

Please take a look [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172) to understand the difference between the padding mechanisms and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28131076/589259) for the difference in Java.

I guess Android is using a stripped down Bouncy Castle provider (it was one of the reasons that SpongyCastle was lounged), which would explain the differences between Android and the Java SE provider.

Comment: same problem KeyGenerator AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding implementation not found, i will try SpongyCastle

Comment: @GaneshP: You're not paying attention to what he wrote.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I think that was an old comment, the accept of the answer is still there. I changed my answer once to include the KeyGenerator comment.

Comment: I was worried he was focusing solely on the second half of your answer.